# WordPress fails to embed video URL on specific theme

Tags: themes, oembed, youtube

My developer created custom theme for WP, and for some reason Wordpress fails to embed video URL on user-end.  Everything is fine with Default WP themes, also video is fine on visual mode, but if I try to switch to this theme- I see only the video URL, but not embed video.

Looks like we need to add something to our theme, but can't find any manual - what we need to add to function.php?

thanks

Comment: This ought to be handled by a default filter, but I can't see it at first glance. Does your custom theme remove any default filters? It oughtn't matter, but does your theme keep all the common page structure e.g. does it still call wp_head() ? (I think that's only used by the oembed code for being embedded though, not embedding)

Comment: I'm not sure about default filters, but for sure there is wp_head